# In WP8.1, where does Acrobat Reader get/store PDFs?

Tags: 8.1, file-transfer, pdf

I need to know the folder where I can add some PDFs to Windows Phone 8.1 so they can be found by the Adobe Acrobat Reader app.  I've placed a PDF in /phone/Documents and every other folder I can see.  Adobe Reader still does not see the PDFs.

There are currently no PDFs in Adobe Reader's list, so I cannot search for existing filenames and see which folder it is in.  There does not seem to be any way in Adobe Reader's interface to import PDFs.  I just want to copy to the correct folder and have them listed for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely Adobe Reader does not keep the copy of the PDFs. It just keeps the most recent list. You can copy your pdfs to any place on your phone and open them via the Adobe Reader app. The most obvious place is the Documents folder on your phone. Copy the files there from the PC using the USB connection. To browse the folders on Windows Phone you need an app. The native app from Microsoft is called [Files](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-au/store/app/files/762e837f-461d-4847-8399-3526f54fc25e). However, it works with Windows 8.1 only. If you still have not upgraded your Windows Phone software then you can use any other apps. I like [Files&Folders Pro](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/files-folders-pro/ec460870-3353-4d18-86e1-4b30cdabb432) (it is a paid app, but I got it for free as part of a promotion).

Once you open the pdf via the Adobe Reader app it will appear in its recent list

Comment: Well I've definitely copied them into the Documents folder and they do not show up in Adobe Acrobat Reader.  So as of yet I'm unable to figure out where Reader is searching for PDFs that are present.

Comment: As I said above, the reader is not searching. It keeps it own internal database of what was opened before, similar to Word or Excel on the PC keeps the list of 10-15 most recent open files. Try to open the pdf via the file browser and the file will be added to adobe's list

Comment: Ah what a terrible implementation!  But correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

You have a folder named Documents in your phone (I have in my Nokia Lumia 920) put your .pdf files there. Use Office app, tap phone and you will see displayed the .pdf docs.